# RewriteRule htaccess $1 refferring to php file itself

Tags: php, .htaccess

**CODE :**

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule    ^(.*)/*$    base.php?request=$1    [NC,L]
```

**base.php**

```
<?php
    echo "this is base.php <br/> and Get Vaiables <br> ";
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

*for the request:*

```
localhost/blahblahproject/hello
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

> this is base.php
>   and Get Vaiables
>   Array ( [request] => hello )

**Current RESULT:**

> this is base.php
>   and Get Vaiables
>   Array ( [request] => base.php )

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /base.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]` I don't get your `/*` part...

Comment: if the user types 
localhost/blahblahproject/hello//////// or atleast
localhost/blahblahproject/hello/

Answer (score 1):

Change your .htaccess rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /base.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input ... QSA works but i dont know why its working if you could tell me how it works i will be grateful.

Comment: QSA is for Query String Append. See this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` only redirects url to your get parameter. To retrieve the url value, use `parse_url` or similar command.

I have a function like this to do the job:

```
/**
 * Sets current request url
 */
private function setUrl() {
    $path = parse_url( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], PHP_URL_PATH );
    $pathTrimmed = trim( $path, '/' );
    $pathTokens = explode( '/', $pathTrimmed );

    if ( substr( $path, -1 ) !== '/' ) {
        array_pop( $pathTokens );
    }

    $url = end( $pathTokens );

    $this -> url = $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the string after the last "/", change your .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ base.php?request=$1    [NC,L]
```